# can't set value of form input javascript

Tags: javascript, variables, dom

I assign `document.getElementById("outcome").value` to variable `outcome`.
When I click the button, I want to set value of input that has id "outcome" to "Something".

But when I execute my code below, input form outcome was not set.
Still, input form outcome is nothing happened.

```
function throwDice() {

    var point=document.getElementById("point").value;
    var outcome=document.getElementById("outcome").value;
    outcome=Somthing;
}
```

After that I modify my code right this.

```
function throwDice() {

    var point=document.getElementById("point").value;

    document.getElementById("outcome").value="Something";
}
```

All I do is that remove assigning variable outcome and 
assign "Something" to `document.getElementById("outcome").value` directly.
In this case value of input form outcome is "Something".

My question is why `outcome="Something"` isn't operate.

Comment: Variables aren't references to properties.

Answer (score 2):

**Situation:**

In your first code, you are only overwriting `outcome` variable value with  `"Something"` instead of writing it into element with `id` `outcome`, so if you write:

**Explanation:**

Here you declared `outcome` variable and set its value to the value of your input:

```
var outcome=document.getElementById("outcome").value;
```

And here in this line you are resetting `outcome` variable to `"Something"`

```
outcome=Somthing;
```

So in this case `outcome` variable was just holding the input value, then you changed it to `"Something"`.

So to answer your question: *why outcome="Something" isn't operate?*, it's because `outcome` doesn't refer the `input` element `value`, but only holds its `value`.

**In other words:**

So in your first code you were just doing something like this:

```
var outcome = 5;     //outcome here is 5
outcome = "Something";    //outcome is changed to "Something"
```

In JavaScript variables are loosly typed that's why you see this behaviour, you can take a look at [**Understanding Loose Typing in JavaScript**](https://dzone.com/articles/understanding-loose-typing-jav) for further reading.

Comment: although my terrible English, You answer to my question. Thank you for your rapid answer. I understand my mistake.

Comment: @nuroococoa if it helps you can you please accept my answer. Thank you